# Can I solve this problem with matrices?

Tags: matrices, algorithms, problem-solving

So I have some two dimensional data sets thats I want to analyse. They can be viewed in 2D form as below:

## $M1$:

$$\begin{matrix}00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 66
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 55 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 44 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00\end{matrix}$$

## $M2$:

$$\begin{matrix} 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 30 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 \end{matrix}$$

What I am trying to achieve is to see how the points in $M1$ relate to $M2$, using weighted distances

$$\begin{matrix} 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11
\\0.11 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.11
\\0.11 & 0.25 & 0.66 & 0.66 & 0.66 & 0.25 & 0.11
\\0.11 & 0.25 & 0.66 & 1.00 & 0.66 & 0.25 & 0.11
\\0.11 & 0.25 & 0.66 & 0.66 & 0.66 & 0.25 & 0.11
\\0.11 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.11
\\0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 \end{matrix}$$

So we get this for the $55$ point: 
$$\begin{matrix}00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 7.5 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00\end{matrix}$$

And this for the $44$ point:

$$\begin{matrix}00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 3.3 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00\end{matrix}$$

Which summed together give this:

$$\begin{matrix}00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 10.8 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00
\\00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00\end{matrix}$$

I can do this using a programming (or scripting) language, but I am sure that there must be some way to construct the weighted distance matrix for M1 (either one for all points or one for each point) and then use a series of transforms to get the end result... But I can't for the life of me find anything that does this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is going on here... Are these all matrices?

Comment: Yes, yes they are